# Identify if transaction happened during a person shift time in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider 3 columns, transaction time , shift start time and shift end time. All time are in 24hr format. I wanted to understand the transaction that happened within a shift

| Transaction_time | Shift_Start | Shift_End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 12 | 20 |
| 11 | 6 | 14 |
| 2 | 22 | 6 |
| 17 | 1 | 9 |

Required output:

| Transaction_time | Shift_Start | Shift_End | shift_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 12 | 20 | On shift |
| 11 | 6 | 14 | on shift |
| 2 | 22 | 6 | on shift |
| 17 | 1 | 9 | off shift |

case when transaction_time between shift_start and shift_end  then 'on shift'
when transaction_time <shift_start or transaction_time > shift_end then 'off shift'
end

How to handle 3rd line situation, transactions basically happened at 2am, shift started at 22hrs and ended at 6hrs next day).
This transaction basically happened during on shift, but the above case statement won't return a valid output

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression with `AND` and `OR`:

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE
       WHEN ( shift_start <= shift_end
            AND  transaction_time BETWEEN shift_start AND shift_end
            )
       OR   (   shift_start > shift_end
            AND (  transaction_time BETWEEN shift_start AND 23
                OR transaction_time BETWEEN 0 AND shift_end
                )
            )
       THEN 'On Shift'
       ELSE 'Off Shift'
       END AS shift_flag
FROM   table_name t
```